# Sublime Text 2 - Jump to a specific word

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text and use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search tool very often. However everytime I use it, it highlight the word I am looking work and I then have to click on it to start typing there.

What is the shortcut to directly jump to the word I am looking for?

Many thanks

Comment: Press escape, you should be able to edit the current zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that as you said <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> rather than <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> you are using the OSX version of Sublime Text.

The [Windows / Linux shortcut](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html) for ***Goto word in current file*** is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

But if you look at the corresponding list for [OSX shortcuts](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html) that one is missing.

(I am currently on a Windows machine so I can't test the lack of an OSX shortcut)

Comment: thanks. would there be a way to add this shortcut manually on a mac?

Comment: preferences > keybindings. I have *{ "keys": ["ctrl+;"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "text": "#"} },* there (win)